# serialize all type of objects to store session in state server or sql server

Tags: c#, asp.net, serialization, session-state-server, state-server

I have a web application with ASP.NET web forms and I want to store session in state server or SQL server , in those cases my classes must be serialized, but I have some  non-serializable fields or class (like  `IIdentity`). what’s the best way to do this?

I tried `ISurrogateSelector` interface and implement two method (`GetObjectData`,`SetOPbjectData`)  and it works but may exist too many non-serilizable objects and I want a general way to do this.

Comment: Non-serializeble objects are that way because there is no way to actually serialize them even with type specific code, even less via some "general way to do so". You best option is not to store non-serializable objects in session.